# Need LATEX code for this equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations, math-operators, ieeeconf

[image]

Hi, i'm writing a conference paper and i'm new to Latex. It's hard for me to write this equation. Kindly help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Share what you have tried so far and where you are facing problems. If you have not tried anything yet, you may try using the `cases` environment which provides such output. There are many examples available on the internet (even on this site).

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and whether you're ok with using the `amsmath` package. Also, do the equations have to be numbered or unnumbered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
u(x,t)&=\begin{cases} 
    \left\{\frac{2c}{a}\sin^2\left[\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}(x-ct)\right]\right\}^{1/n}, & |x-ct|\leq\frac{\pi}{\mu},\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}\\
u(x,t)&=\begin{cases} 
    \left\{\frac{2c}{a}\cos^2\left[\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}(x-ct)\right]\right\}^{1/n}, & |x-ct|\leq\frac{\pi}{2\mu},\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]